# How to use visNetworkProxy in Shiny to interact with Nodes based on Nodes ids

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rstudio, visnetwork

I am building a network analysis in Shiny app.

I want to use the **visNetworkProxy** function to **interact (focus/select) nodes** based on **nodes ids**.

However, **"nodes$id" in selectInput in UI** has to be **pre-defined**. In this case, I have to **define nodes&edges outside of server** instead of inside of server.

Due to the nature of my project, I **have to keep nodes & edges defined in the server** to keep them updated with the database.

Below is my code:

```
  server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network_proxy_nodes <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = "blue")
  })


  observe({
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visFocus(id = input$Focus, scale = 4)
  })

  observe({
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visNodes(color = input$color)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("color", "Color :",
                  c("blue", "red", "green")),
      selectInput("Focus", "Focus on node :",
                  nodes$id)
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_nodes", height = "400px")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to **interact with nodes with nodes$id** while **keep nodes and edges inside the server**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that'll work. You need to dynamically render the `selectInput` based on the nodes.

```
library(shiny)

 server <- function(input, output) {

  # minimal example
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

  output$network_proxy_nodes <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = "blue")
  })


  observeEvent(input$Focus, {
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visFocus(id = input$Focus, scale = 4)
  })

  observeEvent(input$color, {
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visNodes(color = input$color)
  })

  output$choose_node <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Focus", "Focus on node :",
                nodes$id)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("color", "Color :",
                  c("blue", "red", "green"))
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_nodes", height = "400px"),
      uiOutput("choose_node")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT**

Following your comment, adding a button.

```
library(shiny)

 server <- function(input, output) {

  # minimal example
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

  output$network_proxy_nodes <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = "blue")
  })


  observeEvent(input$focus_now, {
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visFocus(id = input$Focus, scale = 4)
  })

  observeEvent(input$color, {
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visNodes(color = input$color)
  })

  output$choose_node <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Focus", "Focus on node :",
                nodes$id)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("color", "Color :",
                  c("blue", "red", "green"))
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_nodes", height = "400px"),
      uiOutput("choose_node"),
      actionButton("focus_now", "FOCUS")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you John! It worked very well on my end. Just have 1 question: by applying your code, the app will automatically focus on the default node (1 in this example) when I run the app. However, I want the app not to focus on any node when I open it even if the default node id is in the select box. Do you have any thoughts on this? I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are you OK adding an `actionButton` and have the node focus on click?

Comment: Yea, adding an actionButton is a good idea. But I am a bit confused why it can automatically focus on the default node after you add "choose_node" output from my original code. I am wondering if there is a way to solve this issue without adding acionButton. This is just for curiosity, it is fine to use the action button if there is no alternatives. Thank you so much!

Comment: You could add an option in the selectInput say “No focus.” And add an if statement in the proxy to not focus if ... (edited code above with actionButton)